# reading specific row of csv into php

Tags: php, android, csv

I have one large csv file with 100000 customer details.
I want to fetch data for my android application. 
I want to read specific row from csv file.
like I want all details of customer whoes `cust_id` is 070507

Reading this much big file in php using this method will take too much time.

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
}
fclose($handle)
}
```

I want a simple solution.
and If this is simplest method then please tell me how to read specific row ?

Comment: This is the convenient one you are using I guess :).

Comment: then how to read specific row from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file into an array using file(), then you can target the specific line and parse it to CSV

```
$lines = file('test.csv');
$row = $lines[70507]; // Assuming one header row
$csvdata = str_getcsv($row); // Parse line to CSV

$num = count($data); // Get number of columns
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { // Loop through columns
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n"; // Echo column
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you read specific row.

```
$ch = fopen($link_to_file);
$found = '';

/* If your csv file's first row contains Column Description you can use this to remove the first row in the while */
$header_row = fgetcsv($read_file);

/* This will loop through all the rows until it reaches the end */
while(($row = fgetcsv($ch)) !== FALSE) {

    /* $row is an array of columns from that row starting at 0 */
    $first_column = $row[0];

    /* Here you can do your search */
    /* If found $found = $row[1]; */
    /* Now $found will contain the 2nd column value (if found) */

}
```